# Only first function is called when 2 functions are called on separate threads from main()

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to run two functions parallelly, so instead of sharing that large code I have written a simpler version of that as shown below

```
import thread


def function1():
    print "in function 1"

def function2():
    print "in function 2"


# Create two threads as follows

def main():
    try:
       thread.start_new_thread( function1())
       thread.start_new_thread( function2())

    except Exception:
       print Exception.message

    while 1:
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am getting following output

```
in function 1
<attribute 'message' of 'exceptions.BaseException' objects>
```

any reasons why function # 2 is not working

Comment: Why is your question tagged python-3.x but you don't have parentheses around your print statements?

Comment: I just checked I am using 2.7 in pycharm , sorry about that, I will change the tags, Thanks for letting me know

Comment: Try it without the `try..except` blocks.  You should get a much more informative error message with traceback.

Comment: thread.start_new_thread( function1(10))
TypeError: start_new_thread expected at least 2 arguments, got 1

Comment: You are passing the result of `function1` by `function1()`, you should send function itself `thread.start_new_thread( function1, [10])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that  start_new_thread expects at least 2 arguments, so if your function does not take any arguments , then pass it like

```
 thread.start_new_thread( function_name,())
```

Below is the working piece of code

```
import thread


def function1():
    try:
        print "in function 1  \n"
    except Exception:
        print Exception.message

def function2():
    try:
        print "in function 2 \n"
    except Exception:
        print Exception.message


# Create two threads as follows

def main():

    try:
       thread.start_new_thread( function1,())
       thread.start_new_thread( function2 ,())
    except Exception:
        Exception.message

    while 1:
        pass



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a second argument in your `thread.start_new_thread` call. The arguments to the function should be passed as a tuple. In your case this is an empty tuple.

```
import thread

def function1():
    print "in function 1"

def function2():
    print "in function 2"

# Create two threads as follows

def main():

   thread.start_new_thread( function1, ())
   thread.start_new_thread( function2, ())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[Python thread.start_new_thread documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html#thread.start_new_thread)

Comment: Thanks a lot, below is the code that I ran, it's working but when we remove `while 1` there is an error, do you know why?